# Does angular/material2 have a grid system

Tags: angular-material2

angular/material2 is just out in beta.0 with a new site.

But I cant find out if it has a responsiv grid system for layout, like bootstrap.

Comment: There is angular material 2, but it is not finished yet. You can find more information here: https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: Yes I am talking about it, look in the header (-:

Comment: Everything they support is in github's readme. They have flex-layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in app.module.ts:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@NgModule({

  import:[

    FlexLayoutModule

  ])}
```

then follow the handbook below to learn how to use it in your HTML:
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use this Package |[ng2-flex-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-flex-layout)|

And [flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Angular/Material2 does have grid layout: [material grid layout](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview)

Comment: Is this the preferred approach to @angular/flex-layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337959/does-angular-material-have-a-grid-system/69194634#69194634) about creating your own Angular Grid System from scratch.