# does angular material have a grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, angular-material2

I'm starting a project with angular material.
Does it have a native system for positioning elements in a responive grid like bootstrap does ?

Otherwise is it ok practice to combine material design with bootstrap for the grid system ?

Maybe I am taking the wrong aproach to the problem.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you asking about material1 or material2 ?

Comment: I am using material 2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using Material2, you can use [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation) for responsiveness. It compliments Angular2 well and is lightweight.

Basically Material2 + Flex-layout is equivalent to Bootsrap library.

Here's an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/a4iASMaZqQZNmuuQUapb?p=preview) of how flex-layout can be used for grid system/responsiveness with Angular/Material2.

Sample Code showing use of flex-layout API:

```
<div fxShow.xs="true" fxShow="false" >Screen size <h1>XS</h1></div>
    <div fxShow.sm="true" fxShow="false" >Screen size <h1>SM</h1></div>
    <div fxShow.md="true" fxShow="false" >Screen size <h1>MD</h1></div>
    <div fxShow.lg="true" fxShow="false" >Screen size <h1>LG</h1></div>
    <div fxShow.xl="true" fxShow="false" >Screen size <h1>XL</h1></div>

    <div fxLayout="row" 
         fxLayout.xs="column"
         fxLayoutGap="10px"
         fxLayoutAlign.xs="center center"
         fxLayoutWrap>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="7">Div 1</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="6">Div 2</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="5">Div 3</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="4">Div 4</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="3">Div 5</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="2">Div 6</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="1">Div 7</div>
      <div class="sample-div" fxFlexOrder.lt-md="0">Div 8</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think where this is correct `Basically Material2 + Flex-layout is equivalent to Bootsrap library.`? Because of `Flex-layout` is only provide a Grid system. But Boostrap provides so many other layout options such as `Container` and `Utility` classes and etc.

Comment: why can't we just admit it, the answer is NO, angular material doesn't have a css style grid system.

Answer (score 16):

This site describes how to add the bootstrap grid to a Angular Material project:
https://www.amadousall.com/the-good-parts-of-bootstrap-4-you-are-missing-in-your-angular-material-projects/

A summary of the steps described in the article:

Add bootstrap to your project:

> npm install bootstrap --save

## src/styles.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

@import 'variables';

// Imports functions, variables, and mixins that are needed by other Bootstrap files
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
// Import Reboot
@import '~bootstrap/scss/reboot';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/grid'; // add the grid
@import '~bootstrap/scss/utilities'; // add css utilities

@import 'reset';
```

## src/_variables.scss:

The _variables.scss Sass partial allows us to customize Bootstrap - more precisely, the parts of Bootstrap that we will be using

```
$link-color: #3f51b5;
$link-hover-color: currentColor;
$link-hover-decoration: none;

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0, // handset portrait (small, medium, large) | handset landscape (small)
  sm: 600px, // handset landscape (medium, large) | tablet portrait(small, large)
  md: 960px, //  tablet landscape (small, large)
  lg: 1280px, // laptops and desktops
  xl: 1600px // large desktops
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 600px,
  md: 960px,
  lg: 1280px,
  xl: 1600px
);
```

## src/_reset.scss:

The _reset.scss Sass partial allows us to override some of the Bootstrap styles we don't want

```
* {
  &:active,
  :focus {
    outline: none !important;  // 1
  }
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 0; // 2
}


a:not(.mat-button):not(.mat-raised-button):not(.mat-fab):not(.mat-mini-fab):not([mat-list-item]) {
  color: #3f51b5; // 3
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 14):

Looks like Angular Material (7.0.3) still do not have solid grid system like bootstrap, else they would have included it in their [official documentation](https://material.angular.io)

and we still need to use Anuglar Material because of richer UI/UX.

solution is to take only grid part from bootstrap.

stylesheet`bootstrap-grid.css`  can be used as mentioned in  [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files) or corresponding [cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap-grid.css) can be used to utilize bootstrap provided grid functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Because Angular Material lacks of a Grid system, You can create one by your own using Bootstrap 5 wrapping it into Angular components. It's an example of a nested Grid you can have by creating your own grid components:

```
<box containerFluid>
  <box row [spacingY]="4">
    <box [md]="4">
      <box row>
        <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
        <box [md]="6">
          <box row>
            <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
            <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
          </box>
        </box>
      </box>
    </box>
    <box [md]="4"> Item </box>
    <box [md]="4"> Item </box>
    <box [md]="6">
      <box row>
        <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
        <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
      </box>
    </box>
    <box [md]="3"> Item </box>
    <box [md]="3">
      <box row>
        <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
        <box [md]="6"> Item </box>
      </box>
    </box>
  </box>
</box>
```

The full working example is on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYtW9siws1c). You can have column spacing, breakpoints, margin, paddings and gutters. All what you need for a basic grid system.