# Display material angular cards css

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I use angular cli 6 and angular material 2.

I would like to limit the number of cards to 8 per line in large , 4 in medium and 1 in small but I do not know how with this css. Here is my template.

There are many example but i don't understand good....

Would you also know a good tutorial for css and angular material 2. Thank you very much?

//html

```
<div class="grid">
<ng-container  *ngFor="let referentielToDisplay  of referentielsToDisplay | async" >

  <mat-card *ngIf="toppings.value.includes(referentielToDisplay.speSS)">
        <mat-card-title-group>
          <img mat-card-image    src="{{ referentielToDisplay?.url }}" alt="SNFGEu" >
          <mat-card-title><h5>{{ referentielToDisplay?.nomSS }}</h5></mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle *ngIf="referentielToDisplay?.nomSS2">{{ referentielToDisplay?.nomSS2 }}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-title-group>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>{{ referentielToDisplay?.descriptionSS }}</p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
     <a target="_blank" href="{{ referentielToDisplay?.webSS }}">Accès web</a>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>

</ng-container>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
.grid {
     display: flex;
    }

    mat-card {
      width: 400px;
      margin: 15px;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      mat-card {
        margin: 15px 0 !important;
      }
    }
    mat-card:hover {
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 16px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
    mat-card-title {
      margin-right: 5px;

    }
    mat-card-title-group {
      margin: 0;
    }

    img {
   width:70px;
   height :70px;

    margin-left: 5px;
    }

    span {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

Comment: I would like you to check: [angular material grid system ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337959/does-angular-material-have-a-grid-system) on stackoverflow question.

Comment: Can you use bootstrap? That would be a breeze with the flex model in the latest version.

Comment: can you show me an example. i know bootstrap but i want test angular flex layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i used bootstrap :

```
<div  class="row no-gutter">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let referentielToDisplay  of referentielsToDisplay | async">
      <ng-container  *ngIf="toppings.value.includes(referentielToDisplay.speSS)">
  <div class="col"  >
  <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title-group>
          <img mat-card-image    src="{{ referentielToDisplay?.url }}" alt="SNFGEu" >
          <mat-card-title><h5>{{ referentielToDisplay?.nomSS }}</h5></mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle *ngIf="referentielToDisplay?.nomSS2">{{ referentielToDisplay?.nomSS2 }}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-title-group>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>{{ referentielToDisplay?.descriptionSS }}</p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
     <a target="_blank" href="{{ referentielToDisplay?.webSS }}">Accès web</a>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
      </div>
    </ng-container> 
       </ng-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid inconsistencies, you can use a grid system using boostrap 4 or Angular Flex Layout.

Comment: Where i must write the ngfor and the ngif condition to have a correct grid ?